# Android: Re-use support map fragment inside viewpager fragment to keep FULL state

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application that uses actionbarsherlock and google maps. I have 3 main tabs in the application and when you navigate two tabs away, the first tab is destroyed. I set the setOffscreenPageLimit() to 2 but I would like to fix this issue correctly and sometimes when users get back to the map view the map is empty and non-responsive. I keep the fragments in an array inside my actionbar activity to try to keep them from being destroyed which used to work with a previous version of google play but in moving to 7.0.0 I had to restructure my code. I am rather inexperienced with fragments so the issue may lie there, though the zoom and position of the map are maintained and nothing else (options, markers, etc..)

My code is as follows:

**EDIT:**

**When I come back, the map saves my zoom and where I am looking, but the listeners and markers are gone. Any tasks that use the map are no longer connected**

// ActionBarActivity.java

```
public class ActionBarActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener, OnPageChangeListener {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    String pageString = "map_view";
    // Holder for the fragments used
    List<SherlockFragment> frags;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // *** I would like for the code to work WITHOUT the following line ***
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Get Actionbar
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

        // Get tabs
        ActionBar.Tab mapTab = bar.newTab()
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_map)
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setTag("map");

        ActionBar.Tab listTab = bar.newTab()
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_view_as_list)
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setTag("list");

        // Get tabs
        ActionBar.Tab photoFeedTab = bar.newTab()
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_camera)
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setTag("photo");


        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.addTab(mapTab);
        bar.addTab(listTab);
        bar.addTab(photoFeedTab);

        frags = Arrays.asList(null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final String[] mPageTitles;

        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mPageTitles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mPageTitles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPageTitles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    pageString = "map_view";
                    if(frags.get(0) == null) {
                        ViewMap vm = new ViewMap();
                        vm.setRetainInstance(true);
                        frags.set(0, vm);
                    }
                    f = frags.get(0);
                    // pass through the bundle holding lat/long
                    // to move the camera (if present)
                    Bundle showData = getIntent().getExtras();
                    if (showData != null) {
                        f.setArguments(showData);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pageString = "list_view";
                    if(frags.get(1) == null) {
                        frags.set(1, new ListViewHubba());
                    }
                    f = frags.get(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pageString = "Photo_feed";
                    if(frags.get(2) == null) {
                        frags.set(2, new PhotoFeedList());
                    }
                    f = frags.get(2);
                    break;
            }
            return f;
        }
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        position = position % getSupportActionBar().getNavigationItemCount();
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

// ViewMap.java

```
public class ViewMap extends SherlockFragment {

    public GoogleMap mMap;
    private View rootView = null;
    Context context;
    private View v;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    boolean fetched = false;
    SupportMapFragment fragment;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = getMapFragment();
        if (fragment == null) {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Fragment was null.");
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, fragment).commit();
        } else {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Fragment was Not null.");
        }


    /**
     * at this time google play services are not initialize so get map
     * and add what ever you want to it in onResume() or onStart()
     */
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setupMapIfNeeded();
    }

    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        if(rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_map_activity, container,
                    false);
        } else {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Non null root view.");
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setupMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = fragment.getMap();
            fetched = false;
        }

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        // and only reload it if we haven't already fetched
        if (mMap != null && !fetched) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            isHybrid = false;
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // Check if current location is available, otherwise default to riley
                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                LatLng Center;
                if (location != null) {
                    // Get current location info
                    Center = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                } else {
                    // default to riley
                    Center = new LatLng(42.4409010, -83.3978000);
                }

                // set camera position
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(Center)
                        .zoom(CAMERA_ZOOM)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(30)
                        .build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            /**
             * Show loading message if first time fetching.
             */
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                    "Fetching spots...", true);

            Spot.getAllSpots(mMap, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), progressDialog);
            fetched = true;

            //... custom map options here ...
        }
    }

    private SupportMapFragment getMapFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "using getFragmentManager");
            fm = getFragmentManager();
        } else {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "using getChildFragmentManager");
            fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        }

        return (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
    }
}
```

// view_map_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_container">

        <!-- The map fragment will go here -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not getting any error/crashes but when I get back to the map view from the furthest most right tab, my zoom and location is still there but all of the markers are gone. I have a workaround to add them back when the fragment is navigated back to -- but it is too slow since I have a ton of markers.

Does anyone know of a way to keep the nested child supportmapfragment around? I have been working on this for a very long time and could really use some help...

Comment: You are using ActionBarSherlock??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in onCreate() method to ask the supportmapfragment to retain points etc when recycling the map. This could anyway require time to save and restore thousands of markers, and you have no alternatives, big data are big data :D

EDIT: anyway it seems you already are retaining instance... does this work?

**EDIT2:** 
Looking at the maps demo, there is one "MapRetain" which running on my device work. Maybe all of your touches to fragments and "SupportMapFragment.newInstance()" breaks up everything...

```
/**
 * This shows how to retain a map across activity restarts (e.g., from screen rotations), which can
 * be faster than relying on state serialization.
 */
public class RetainMapDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // First incarnation of this activity.
            mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using it both on the parent fragment and on the map fragment but it doesn't seem to work. The listeners on the map no longer work when coming back to the tab and all the functions that use the map seem to not be connected to the map anymore (as if mMap was replaced silently or created new when i come back -- even though the child fragment and the map are not null)... not sure if that helps solve the issue.

Comment: The map does save where I am looking (zoom, etc) but all the listeners and markers are gone. Very strange...

Comment: Yes, the map retains the map objects and location because are part of it, listeners are part of your logic/classes so are not retained (you have to set them again when restoring instance). Its normal behavior, memory leak otherwise!

Comment: Yeah that is what the normal expected behavior is because of the garbage collection but I was wondering if there was any way to keep the markers on the map when it is restored? It takes a long time to get them onto the map (it lags because it is freeing memory when adding the markers) Is there any way to get it to keep the markers? Adding the listeners is quick.

Comment: This would work if I were using FragmentActivities. I have a fragment with a nested map fragment inside (Thus I need to add the new instance the first time through so I can inject it into the view). It should only be called the first time through or so I think so this solution is similar to what I am doing. I have updated my code to use the newer getmapasync() if posting that code would help.

I can try something more similar to this and report back.